# How can I reinstall Broadcom STA drivers?

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom

I'm having problems enabling the Broadcom STA proprietary wireless driver.

I was using it previously, since I installed Ubuntu 10.10. I found out recently that this was causing problems with wired connectivity (a problem for another thread) so I switched to the Broadcom B43 wireless driver, which solved that problem. One problem that it raised is that wireless was often quite slow, especially if I had two thing simultaneously downloading. To verify this I testing download something in three areas of the city that I live in, each using a different ISP and the results were the same

So, I want to switch back to the Broadcom STA proprietary wireless driver, but when I activate it it doesn't work. It reads "This driver is activated but not in use".

What can I do to make it work? I've tried adding "wl" to /etc/modules and have followed advice from [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604868) but it hasn't worked of them have worked

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10. My computer specs: Dell Studio 1555: Pentium Dual Core T4300(2.1GHz,800MHz,1MB), 4096MB 800MHz DDR2 Dual Channel, 512 MB ATI Mobility RADEON HD 4570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to purge these things, reboot and go to proprietary drivers?

```
sudo aptitude purge i8kutils bcmwl-kernel-source bcmwl5700-source bcmwl-modealiases broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source b43-fwcutte
```